# Unity3D Coroutine Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm stuck at Unity scripting. I got 3 files : **Scene.cs** , **Player.cs** and **NetworkUtil.cs** . I can't compile my code, as I don't know how to pass Coroutine response back to Scene.

In `Scene.cs` ( `MonoBehavior` class ) :

```
void OnGUI() {
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "Register")) {
    StartCoroutine(registerPlayer());
  }
}
IEnumerator registerPlayer() {
  return Player.NewPlayer("Raptor"); // since Player is not IEnumerator, this line causes error.
}
```

In `Player.cs` ( `Object` class ) :

```
public static Player NewPlayer(string name) {
  Player p = new Player();
  result = p.tryRegister();
  if(result) {
    return p;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

private bool tryRegister() {
  Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  data.Add("some_key", "some_value");
  NetworkUtil.ExecuteAPI(data);
}
```

In `NetworkUtil.cs` ( `Object` class ) :

```
public static IEnumerator ExecuteAPI(Dictionary<string, string> data) {
  WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
  form.AddField("mode", request);
  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in data) {
    form.AddField(entry.Key, entry.Value);
  }

  WWW handler = new WWW(API_URL, form);
  yield return handler;
  if(handler.error != null) {
    Debug.Log("Error occurred: " + handler.error); // Server Error
  } else {
    Debug.Log("Response: " + handler.text);
  }
}
```

How can I change the codes to make the flow complete?

Note: In `Object` class, `StartCoroutine()` does not exist.

---

**EDIT**

I have changed my codes to use Delegates & Events:

```
// DelegatesAndEvents.cs
public class DelegatesAndEvents : MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void RegisterEventHandler(Player player);
    public static event RegisterEventHandler onPlayerRegister;

    public static void NewPlayerRegistered(Player player) {
        if(onPlayerRegister != null) {
            onPlayerRegister(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Scene.cs`:

```
void Start() {
  DelegatesAndEvents.onPlayerRegister += this.userRegistered;
}

public void userRegistered(Player player) {
  Debug.Log("User registered.");
}
```

How should I put the trigger in `NetworkUtil.cs` & `Player.cs` ?

Comment: If you are using Delegates... I notice you have the reference being added in the Start() method.  Be sure to add the reference in the OnEnable() method and then remove it in the OnDisable() method to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that, because you not only need to return an `IEnumerator`, but it's Unity itself that will iterate on it, so you don't have the possibility to catch the return value.

Technically is possible to do the following:

```
IEnumerator registerPlayer() {
  yield return Player.NewPlayer("Raptor"); // this is legal, player will be the Current value of the IEnumerator
}
```

If you want to do do something like the code above, you need to **wrap** the `coroutine` inside another, and iterate on it by yourself (I did something similar implementing behavior trees):

```
IEnumerator Wrap(IEnumerator playerRegister)
{
  while(playerRegister.MoveNext())
  {
    Player p = playerRegister.Current as Player; //this can be done if you know what you are doing
    yield return null; 
  }
}
```

Another way is not return anything and pass a **delegate** to the `coroutine`, that will be called passing back to the caller the required parameter.

Something like:

```
IEnumerator DoSomething(Action<Response> whenDone)
{
  while (doingSomething)
    yield return null;

  whenDone(response);
}
```

---

EDIT

The other problem with your code is that you are calling another coroutine (`ExecuteAPI`)from inside `Player`'s constructor. 
So, making registerPlayer a coroutine is pointless since you are not yielding anything.

In your case the simplest way to go is to pass a delegate to `ExecuteAPI` that will be called when you receive the response from the server.

Comment: Codes can be compiled with 1st part of script, but I'm not sure how to apply 2nd & 3rd part of script. So how to apply these in my codes? What should be in `OnGUI()` function? After modifying my original codes, the `OnGUI()` contains `StartCoroutine(registerPlayer());`.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit; it seems to point me to correct direction. I try to apply the delegate & events, but I encounter some issues. See my edit in question, thanks.

Comment: Since the WWW async call is in your NetworkUtils class, I guess it's there that you want to raise the event when the response will be received.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do so. But I'm confused again. Since the `NetworkUtil` class is not parenting `MonoBehavior`, `StartCoroutine` does not exist. If I don't use `StartCoroutine`, `ExecuteAPI()` cannot be called. What should I change ?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: pass a reference to a MonoBehavior instance to ExecuteAPI call, and start the coroutine on that object.